# Selecting from listWidget and adding to textedit

Tags: c++, xml, qt, parsing

Ok so title might be understate, I will explain it here. I have a `ListWidget` and a `TextEdit`. So 1st I read an xml file(this xml file has paths for other configuration files). and I store all the paths taken from XML file in a structure like this:

Header

```
struct triStringList
    {
        QString Filename;
        QString block;
        QString flag;
        QString aktioncommand;
    };
    QList<triStringList> allTriList;
    QList <QListWidgetItem*> items;
```

cpp

```
void MainWindow::presetXML()
{
    triStringList triStr;
    QXmlGet xmlget;
    xmlget.load(File.xml);
    xmlget.findAndDescend("HEADER");
    while(xmlget.findNext("HEADER_FILES"))
    {
        triStr.Filename.append(xmlget.getAttributeString("Name"));
        triStr.block.append(xmlget.getAttributeString("BlockNr"));
        triStr.flag.append(xmlget.getAttributeString("FLags"));
        xmlget.descend();
        if(xmlget.findNext("AKTION_COMMAND"))
        {
            triStr.aktioncommand  =xmlget.getAttributeString("Name");
        }
        allTriList.append(triStr);
        xmlget.rise
    }
    for(int i=0; i<allTriList.count(); i++)
    {
        Qstring name;
        QFileInfo file(allTriList[i].Filename);
        name = file.fileName();
        preset_tri_list.append(name);
    }
    ui->listWidgetOutput->addItems(preset_tri_list);
```

Ok so, I add the fileName to the listwidget like I have shown above, All subchild will not have  "Action command" subchild. I have a function which shows this Action command on the `TextEdit` which I spoke about, when the file is clicked in listwidgetoutput:
-1st I take the Selected item
-then I trim the fileName of all the files in the structure.
-I compare it with selected item
-if it matches, i add the respective action command to the text edit.

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidgetOutput_itemSelectionChanged()
{
    QString list;        
    QStringList list1;
    items = ui->listWidgetOutput_TRI->selectedItems();
    qDebug()<<"num: "<<items.count();
    qDebug()<< "all: "<<allTriList.count();
    for(int i=0; i<allTriList.count();i++)
    {
       QFile file(allTriList[i].Filename);
        list = file.fileName();
       list1.append(list);          

       for(int j=0; j<items.count(); j++)
       {              
           if(items[j]->text() == list1[j])
           {
               ui->TextEdit->setText(allTriList[i].aktioncommand);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

But when I click on the file I get:

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:\app\Tools\Qt\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtCore/qlist.h, line 486
```

And the program crashes, From debugging what I have found is it crashes here: `for(int j=0; j<items.count(); j++)` but it is not empty.
Not exactly sure what's happening, I am a Qt Beginner. And sorry for a long post

xml file:

```js
 <Header>
    <TRIGGER Name="%PATH%/file" FLags="C24" BlockNr="C_Blocknr_1"/>
    <TRIGGER Name="%%PATH%/file" FLags="C25" BlockNr="C_Blocknr_2"/>
    <TRIGGER Name="%PATH%/file" FLags="C74" BlockNr="C_Blocknr_6"/>
    <TRIGGER Name="%PATH%/file" FLags="C94" BlockNr="C_Blocknr_1"/>
    <TRIGGER Name="%%PATH%/file" FLags="C20" BlockNr="C_Blocknr_1"/>
    <TRIGGER Name="%%PATH%/file" FLags="C21" BlockNr="C_Blocknr_1"/>
    <TRIGGER Name="%%PATH%/file" FLags="C49" BlockNr="C_Blocknr_1"/>
 </Header>
```

Comment: `list1` can be different size than `items`. Check for that.

Comment: Why are you using `QFile` there?

Comment: [This code](https://ideone.com/zPfBkf) worked fine for me when using your xml snippet. The output is [this](http://pasted.co/01079655).

Comment: I dunno why it's not working for me. it shows FLags = ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand: You have an outer loop (counting var `i`) and an inner loop (counting var `j`) which you use to compare two lists. For each item in the outer loop (`i`) you perform a search of each item in the inner loop (`j`). So in the following line

```
if(items[j]->text() == list1[j])
```

I assume you meant to do the following comparison:

```
if(items[j]->text() == list1[i])
```

Comment: Or just compare it with `list`. `list1` seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: I have another problem, apparently fileName() is not trimming the filepath out, any particular reason why?

Comment: @user5820174 Because it is not supposed to. Use [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#fileName) if you want to do that.

Comment: my list = "%path%/file1%path%/file2". my list1= "%path%/file1 %path%/file1%path%/file2"

Comment: Thanks totally forgot about QFileInfo! totally worked.

Comment: @thuga, Why are my files like "file1  file1file2   file1file2file3" it should be like "file1  file2  file3"

Comment: @user5820174 It seems like you are just debugging the value in a loop. So in the first iteration you have `file1`. In the second you have `file1,file2` and so on.

Comment: Not in that part of program, allTriList[i].Filename only has that kinda files in it.

Comment: @user5820174 You are appending new file name to the same `triStringList`. Either create a new object or replace `triStr.Filename.append` with `triStr.Filename = `. Same goes for other variables.

Comment: Ah! My Saviour! last question,  triStr.flag = xmlget.getAttributeString("FLags") doesn't work. I got no idea why. it returns empty string. even though it's there in xml file.

Comment: @user5820174 Are you sure it's `FLags` and not `Flags`? Check what `QXmlGet::hasAttribute` returns.

Comment: @thuga. Sorry for late reply, It is FLags in the orginal XML file, i tried QXmlGet::hasAttribute, but returns nothing. even though XML file have attribute. I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: @user5820174 What does your xml file look like?

Comment: @thuga i have edited my main post, check my XML file.